# how to apply facet on date field where result should provide number of records for given date

Tags: solr

I have a schema in which we are recording device registration time in field `devRegDt_dt`.

Our service is storing device registration time in this field, and it gets stored in  `2015-09-24T14:05:08Z` format.

We would like to create query which should provide result as:
"2015-09-24" : 5

i.e. `"DATE"` : `<occurances>`

Please note that we are ignoring time in this result and only considering date.

Just in case if this is duplicate, please help with related question.

Thanks.

Comment: thanks @younghobbit for edit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can faceting over date field. 
 Here is sample query:
`http://localhost:8888/solr/lws-map/select?q=*%3A*&wt=json&fl=id&indent=true&facet.range=**facetfield**&facet=true&facet.range.start=NOW-10YEAR&facet.range.end=NOW&facet.range.gap=%2B1MONTH`

Above query facet over last 10 years documents and gap is 1 Month. if you want count day wise then change **facet.range.gap** to **XXXDAY**
Read more about solr date format at [solr wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Working+with+Dates).

Comment: Thanks Rahul.  One more question, When I ran query acc to this facet params, time of field was showing 6:12...  I hope thats OK!

Comment: Also I suggest you to use facet.range.start=NOW/MONTH & facet.range.end=NOW/Month to get consistent count in buckets. Solr internally converts these expressions to timestamp and if you don't round of ranges then every second value of range changes.